# Issue while combing pandas columns and truncating the decimal points without rounding in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have dataframe like below

**Input**

```
 df.head(6)
 Lat       Lon
 13.34563   -9.45
 5.897        10.345
 NaN         NaN
-8.7865      8.2
 4.782833    9.9098
```

I want create a new column called param which contains both `Lat` and `Lon` upto three decimals places without rounding and if only one or two decimals are only present and extra zero make it three decimals

**Expected Output**

```
Param
13.345:-9.450
5.897:10.345
NaN
-8.786:8.200
4.782:9.909
```

Howe  can this be done in python?

**My code**

```
import math
def truncate(f,n):
    return math.floor(f*10**n)
try :
  df['Lat']  = (df['Lat'].apply(lambda x : truncate(x,3)))/1000
except:
    df['Lat']=np.nan


 try :
      df['Lon']  = (df['Lon'].apply(lambda x : truncate(x,3)))/1000
    except:
      df['Lon']=np.nan

df['param'] = df['Lat'].astype(str) + : + shipment['Lon'].astype(str)
```

But this not working. Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `dropna` then `reindex` back

```
def func(y,n):
    if y < 0 :
      return "%0.3f" % (-(y * 10 ** n // -1 / 10 ** n))
    else :
      return "%0.3f" % (y * 10 ** n // 1 / 10 ** n)


df['Param']=df[['Lat','Lon']].dropna().applymap(lambda x : func(x,3) ).agg(':'.join,1).reindex(df.index)


Out[101]: 
         Lat      Lon          Param
0  13.345630  -9.4500  13.345:-9.450
1   5.897000  10.3450   5.897:10.345
2        NaN      NaN            NaN
3  -8.786500   8.2000   -8.786:8.200
4   4.782833   9.9098    4.782:9.909
```

Comment: I have other columns apart from `Lat` and `Lon` also in the  dataframe. So will that work . I need to assign it to new column called 'param` in the dataframe

Comment: @YOBEN_S I like the way you accounted for truncating negative numbers as well!  Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Param'] = df.apply( lambda x:  "%5.3f:%5.3f" % ( x['Lat'],x['Lon'] ) , axis = 1 )
```

Yields:

```
         Lat      Lon          Param
0  13.345630  -9.4500  13.346:-9.450
1   5.897000  10.3450   5.897:10.345
2        NaN      NaN      nan:  nan
3  -8.786500   8.2000   -8.787:8.200
4   4.782833   9.9098    4.783:9.910
```

Comment: First 13.345630 to 13.345 not 13.346

Answer (score 0):

using string methods.

```
s = df.stack().astype(str).str.split('.',expand=True)
s[1] = s[1].str[:3].str.ljust(3,'0')

df['strLat'] =  (s[0] + '.' +  s[1]).unstack().agg(':'.join,1)

print(df)

         Lat      Lon         strLat
0  13.345630  -9.4500  13.345:-9.450
1   5.897000  10.3450   5.897:10.345
2        NaN      NaN            NaN
3  -8.786500   8.2000   -8.786:8.200
4   4.782833   9.9098    4.782:9.909
```